# Firebase Realtime Database Rules - Using a variable as a key in the data key value pair when writing

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, standards, firebase-security

This is a rough example of what my database looks like.

```
"userA": {
    "uf": {
        "userB": "0"
    }
},
"users": {
    "userA": "0",
    "userB": "0",
    "userC": "0"
}
```

And this is a rough example of the rule I am trying to write.

```
//USER ID
"$uid": {

  //USER FRIENDS
  "uf": {

    //FRIEND USER ID
    "$fuid": {

      ".write": "$uid === auth.uid &&
      root.child('users').hasChild($fuid)",
    }
  },
},
```

And this is what I am trying to get working in the simulator

```
//Location /userA/uf/

//Data { "userC": "0" }
```

It seems that the security rule will always deny a write when the "key" for a data key value pair is a variable in my rules, in this case "$fuid". The simulator will return the messages "Simulated set denied" and "Write denied" but won't give me any additional details. I could get around this by writing the following.

```
//Simulation Method set

//Location /userA/uf/userC/

//Data { "0": "0" }
```

But this feels like it's writing unnecessary data to my database. What is the best practice here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your rules give access to `{uid}/uf/{fuid}` but you're trying to write at `{uid}/uf`.

That `{"0": "0"}` is indeed unnecessary, you can just write `"0"`.

If you want to write multiple friends at once, you can perform a [multipath update](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields), or modify your rules to allow writing directly at `{uid}/uf` and `".validate"` the children.

Side note: if your users can be deleted, if user A has user B as a friend and user B is deleted, your rules won't allow user A to remove user B from the friends list. You should take care of that by changing the rules to allow the deletion of friends that do not exist, or by setting up an [`onDelete()` triggered cloud function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#trigger_a_database_function) that would do the cleanup.